# integer parsing from serially received data in arduino

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, cmath

i am receiving serially data in arduino using this code `Serial.print((char)Serial2.read());` :

```
y456x123

y444x333
```

Now I want to store data in x & y variable as `x=123` & `y=456` similarly for second time
`x=333` & `y=444`.

How can i do this?

Comment: decide what gives you call to Serial2.read(). Is this y456x123 or a single char?

Comment: Your string handling is quite broken.  Start with char inData[42] so you'll have an actual array to store characters in.

Answer (score 1):

Wel dude, you'll have about 9 event call (code execution) for each transmission, but you're not making a right parsing because you're giving to atoif function the letters ('x' and 'y').

I suggest you to store all into an array, and then loop into the array and add the numbers into the loop.

To store:

```
array[possition] = received;
possition++;
```

Then, when store it's complete (received == '\n'):

```
if(array[possition] != 'x'){

    x = (x*10) + (int) array[possition];
}
```

this is a simple idea, it needs to be filtered right at the if statement, or it will add both values.

Comment: i have implemented your idea .

Answer (score 0):

it is completly wrong, you have no idea what a pointer is.
this is a big lack of knoledge in C/C++

the fast solution is to use the String object, the best one is to study the C basic is some good book/guide, there is too much about pointer to be written here.